# Does CPH4 exists?

Tags: molecular-biology

What is the purpose of CPH-4? Is it well represented in the movie Lucy?

Comment: there is an enzyme called CPH4 synthase (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6-carboxytetrahydropterin_synthase) but not sure what it does.

Comment: Luc Besson admits (more or less) that the name is made up (http://uproxx.com/gammasquad/2014/07/scarlett-johansson-lucy-clips-luc-besson-addresses-the-haters/) although he claims the molecule is real. Who knows what it is.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is solely based on a science fiction movie. This is more suitable in [Skeptics-SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22785/is-cph4-from-lucy-real/22820#22820